# Can you factor before finding derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Say the function is $y=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$

Can you factor functions before finding the derivative or does that not work?

Comment: Whatever you do to equal things will yield yet equal things.

Comment: How do you propose to factor your function? Whether it is $$\frac{x^2-3}{x-3}$$ or $$x^2-\frac{3}{x}-3,$$ I don't see it.

Comment: The numerator is a difference of squares. I thought I can factor that to (x-3)(x+3) and cancel the x-3 with the numerator, leaving y=x+3

Comment: 3 is not a square. Not in the sense that you mean, anyway. (And you need to use parentheses here $-$ try editing your post.)

Comment: Yeah that was a bad example on my part. I changed the function so the situation matches what I wanted it to. Sorry for the complication.

Comment: When two folks have answered your original question, it is fairly rude to re-post an entirely different example. In the future, please add the edited example at the bottom of your original post, without deleting the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1} = \dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}$ and $g(x) = x+1$ are equal at every real number $x$ except $x = 1$, where $f(x)$ is undefined, but $g(x)$ is defined.

Therefore, $f'(x) = g'(x) = 1$ at every real number $x$ except $x = 1$.

If you used the quotient rule, you get

$f'(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)(2x)-(x^2-1)(1)}{(x-1)^2} = \dfrac{x^2-2x+1}{(x-1)^2} = \dfrac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2} = 1$ (provided $x \neq 1$).

So, yes, you can factor and simplify the function before computing the derivative, but you must be careful to not enlarge the domain of the function or its derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can "factor" the numerator first, and cancel like terms, first before differentiating, but you'll need to exclude any values of $x$ such that $x$ is not defined in the original function.

For your initial example: $$\left(\frac{x^2 - 3}{x-3}\right)'$$ Yes, you can "factor" first before differentiating, but note $$(x^2-3) = (x - \sqrt 3)(x + \sqrt 3)\neq (x-3)(x+3).$$ So you're not going to gain any leverage by factoring the numerator first, since nothing will cancel. So taking the derivative of $$\frac{(x-\sqrt 3)(x+\sqrt 3)}{x - 3}$$ while you'll get the same exact result if you don't factor, will only complicate matters, since to differentiate the factored quotient will require both the product rule and quotient rule, or else the product rule for $3$ functions.

---

In your newly posted example: $$\dfrac{x^2 - 1}{x - 1} = \frac{(x - 1)(x+1)}{x - 1}$$ Yes, indeed, you can (and I'd suggest you should, to simplify the task at hand) factor the numerator, cancel the common factor $(x - 1)$ which appears in both the numerator and denominator...

> but also *need* to make it *very clear in your work* that canceling the common factor is valid **provided** $x\neq 1$, and so neither the resulting function, nor its derivative, are defined at $x = 1$: e.g., $$y = \dfrac{x^2 -1}{x-1} = x+1 \iff x\neq 1$$

If you don't provide a comment to this effect, that information is lost after canceling, and thus incorrectly implying that , e.g., $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ exist, when in reality they don't, given the original function.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Yes.

Factoring an expression preserves the function it represents.  That is, the functions
$$f(x) = (x+1)(x-1)$$
$$g(x) = x^2-1$$
are the *same function*.

Thus, taking the derivative of the factored form *or* the non-factored form is equivalent.

Comment: But I'm cancelling out the (x-1) in the numerator with the one in the denominator as well. Thus, it will be y=x+1. Does this still apply?